# Datepicker not able to just allow future dates on ODOO V11

Tags: datepicker, widget, odoo

Hello team I am using ODOO V11 and a need a rule in the datepicker that  not allow choose past dates.
For that I am using a module from community
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/web_widget_datepicker_options/

I  got some error when I put as parameter 0 in the min date to allow just  dates from the current date:

```
<field name="active_date" options="{'datepicker':{'minDate': '0'}}"/>
```

eError: maxDate() Could not parse date parameter: 0.

When I try pass a specific date it works successfully

```
<field name="active_date" options="{'datepicker':{'minDate': '2018-09-01'}}"/>
```

Could you please take a look and tell me the parameter correctly to put in the option for datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

for making datepicker only accept future dates, you need to change your code into

```
<field name="active_date" options="{'datepicker':{'minDate': 'now'}}"/>
```